# how make listview in Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `ListView` in activity, but I need `ListView` in Fragment. How can I do it? I didn't find nothing about this problem online ...

This is my code for your perusal. Thank you in advance!!!!

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();


    }

    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4,"€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }

    }
    public void showResult(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;

        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){
                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                //if (p.quantità.equals("") && p.quantità.equals(null) ){
                System.out.println("leggo questo record:"+p.name + " " + p.distance + " " + p.quantità );

                System.out.println("leggo questo p.getquatità :"+p.quantità );
                //}
                //else{
                    System.out.println("leggo questo in p.quantità: "+p.getQuantità());
                    int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                    totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //}
            }
        }
//      Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Integer.toString(totalAmount);
        Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NomeDati1", result);
        i.putExtra("NomeDati2", String.valueOf(totalAmount));
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

AND THIS:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.EightFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FiveFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FourFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.NineFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SevenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TwoFragment;

public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "PIZZE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
        adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
        adapter.addFrag(new NineFragment(), "NINE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">ListFragmentDemo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="imgdesc">imgdesc</string>

<string-array name="Planets">
    <item>Sun</item>
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.pavan.listfragmentdemo.MyListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyListFragment.java

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

Comment: but i need also checkbox

Comment: class Planet {
 
 String name;
 int distance;
 String quantità;
 String valuta;
 boolean selected = false;



 public Planet(String name, int distance, String quantità) {
  super();
  this.name = name;
  this.distance = distance;
  this.quantità = quantità;
 }